# Trying to separate spiral data with neural network, learning tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks, classification, tensorflow

I am learning how to use tensorflow without keras, just to make sure I understand tensorflow directly.

I created a spiral-looking datasets with 100 points of each class (200 total), and I created a neural network to classify it. For the life of me I can't figure out how to get a good accuracy. Do you mind looking at my code to see what I did wrong?

From what I've gleaned from various forums, it seems like if I do 4 hidden layers and 14 neurons per layer, I should be able to perfectly separate this dataset. I tried with with learning rate of 0.01, and 20k epochs.

I've tried different combinations of activation functions (tanh, sigmoid, relu, even alternating between them), but the best that I've gotten is around 60 percent, whereas people with less layers and less neurons have gotten close to 90 percent.

What I did NOT do is to create additional features (for example, r and theta), and this was intentional. I'm just curious to see if I can do this by looking at x and y alone.

The code is pasted below, and it includes the code to create the data (and it plots the data).

Thank you in advance!

````
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import tensorflow as tf;
import random;

# Part A
# Gather data and plot
def chooseTrainingBatch(X, Y, n, k):
    indices = range(0,n)
    chosenIndices = random.choices(indices,k=k)
    batchX = X[chosenIndices, :]
    batchY = Y[chosenIndices, :]
    return (batchX, batchY)


def doLinearClassification(n, learning_rate=1, epochs=20, num_hidden_layer_1=100, num_of_layers=4, batch_size = 20):
    d = 1;
    plt.figure();
    X = np.zeros([2*n, 2]);
    Y = np.zeros([2*n, 2]);
    for t in np.arange(1,n+1,d):
        r1 = 50 + 0.2*t;
        r2 = 30 + 0.4*t;
        phi1 = -0.06*t + 3;
        phi2 = -0.08*t + 2;

        x1 = r1 * np.cos(phi1);
        y1 = r1 * np.sin(phi1);
        x2 = r2 * np.cos(phi2);
        y2 = r2 * np.sin(phi2);

        plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='b');
        plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='r');

        X[t-1,0] = x1;
        X[t-1,1] = y1;
        Y[t-1,0] = 1;

        X[n+t-1,0] = x2;
        X[n+t-1,1] = y2;
        Y[n+t-1,1] = 1;


    # declare the training data placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

    # Weights connecting the input to the hidden layer 1
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, num_hidden_layer_1]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_layer_1]))

    # activation of hidden layer 1
    hidden_1_out = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1))

    last_hidden_out = hidden_1_out
    for i in range(1,num_of_layers):    
        # weights connecting the hidden layer i-1 to the hidden layer i
        next_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_layer_1, num_hidden_layer_1]))
        next_b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_layer_1]))

        # activation of hidden layer
        if (i%2 == 0):
            next_hidden_out = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(last_hidden_out, next_W), next_b))
        else:    
            next_hidden_out = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(last_hidden_out, next_W), next_b))

        # update for next loop
        last_hidden_out = next_hidden_out

    # and the weights connecting the last hidden layer to the output layer
    W_end = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_layer_1, 2]))
    b_end = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

    # activation of output layer
    y_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(last_hidden_out, W_end), b_end))

    # loss function
    y_clipped = tf.clip_by_value(y_, 1e-10, 0.9999999)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(y_clipped) + (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_clipped), axis=1))

    # add an optimiser
    optimiser = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

    # finally setup the initialisation operator
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # define an accuracy assessment operation
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    blah = tf.add(tf.matmul(last_hidden_out, W_end), b_end)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # For the purpose of separating dataset, testing data is the entire set
    testingX = X;
    testingY = Y;

    # start the session
    with tf.Session() as sess:
       # initialise the variables
       sess.run(init_op)
       for epoch in range(epochs):
            this_cost = 0
            trainingX, trainingY = chooseTrainingBatch(X, Y, n, batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: trainingX, y: trainingY})
            this_cost += c
            print("Epoch:", (epoch + 1), "cost =", "{:.3f}".format(this_cost))

       #debugging statements
       #this_y = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: testingX, y: testingY})        
       #print("y")
       #print(this_y)
       #this_blah = sess.run(blah, feed_dict={x: testingX, y: testingY})
       #print("blah")
       #print(this_blah)
       #this_y_ = sess.run(y_, feed_dict={x: testingX, y: testingY})
       #print("y_")
       #print(this_y_)
       this_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: testingX, y: testingY})
       print("Accuracy: ", this_accuracy)
       return this_accuracy


# this is the real thing
#doLinearClassification(100, learning_rate = 0.01, epochs=20000, num_hidden_layer_1=14, num_of_layers=4, batch_size=20);

# this is just to debug the code
doLinearClassification(20, learning_rate = 0.01, epochs=200, num_hidden_layer_1=14, num_of_layers=4, batch_size=2);
```
````

Comment: Most probably you are over-fitting the data. Consider decreasing the number of hidden layers and also the number of nodes in the hidden layers.